# jQuery swap div's on mouse over

Tags: jquery

somebody knows a simple jquery script that swaps/changes divs on hover?

E.G.

i have 3 li elements:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#" id="link1">Link1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id="link2">Link2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" id="link3">Link3</a></li>
</ul>
```

and there are 3 DIV containers:

```
<div id="container1">content 1</div>
<div id="container2">content 2</div>
<div id="container3">content 3</div>
```

So, I want when page opens DIV #container1 to be vissible, and #container2, #container3 to bi hidden. Then if user "HOVER" link2 or link3 #container1 gets hidden and #container2 or #container3 will become vissible. I hope you got my point of view.

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nVx7a/1/) if someone will want to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#container2, #container3').hide();
$('li a').mouseover(function(){
    var idx= $(this).attr('id').substr(-1);
    $('#container1, #container2, #container3').hide();
    $('#container'+idx).show();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nVx7a/8/)**

Comment: +1 similar to mine only difference is that .hide could get ugly with a lot of divs, might want to put that in a .each?

Comment: @RickCalder - Nah, I'd assign the divs a class instead. Much easier.

Comment: Fair point. Seeing this makes me rethink mine a little lol, but I'll leave it as is, still the same concept. I wonder if there is any difference at all performance wise between an if statement or hiding divs already hidden? My gut tells me the if is a little more resource heavy, although still a negligible difference.

Answer (score 0):

Set .container to display:none in the CSS

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/nVx7a/14/

jquery:

```
$(".link").hover(function(){
   var whichOne = $(this).attr("id").substring(4);
    $(".container").each(function(){
   if($(this).attr("id")=="container"+whichOne)
   {   
       $(this).show();
   } else {
       $(this).hide();
   }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
       <li><a href="#" id="link1" class="link">Link1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" id="link2" class="link">Link2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" id="link3" class="link">Link3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="container1" class="container">content 1</div>
<div id="container2" class="container">content 2</div>
<div id="container3" class="container">content 3</div>
```